# Tag helper in helper module is not work correctly (rails)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I want to render html to the view using the tag helper with the method declared in the helper module, but it doesn't work.
html code I'd like to render is following:

```html
<span class="flex w-5 h-5 ml-3">
  <span class="animate-ping inline-flex h-full w-full rounded-full aspect-square bg-indigo-400 opacity-75"></span>
  <span class="relative inline-flex w-5 h-5 rounded-full bg-indigo-500 text-gray-200 justify-center aspect-square right-5">
    <%= current_user_active_count %>
  </span>
</span>
```

The code actually written in the helper is below:

```rb
tag.span class: "flex w-5 h-5 ml-3" do
  tag.span class: "animate-ping inline-flex h-full w-full rounded-full aspect-square bg-indigo-400 opacity-75"
  tag.span current_user_active_count, class: "relative inline-flex w-5 h-5 rounded-full bg-indigo-500 text-gray-200 justify-center aspect-square right-5"
end
```

The html rendered by this code is below:

```html
<span class="flex w-5 h-5 ml-3">
  <span class="relative inline-flex w-5 h-5 rounded-full bg-indigo-500 text-gray-200 justify-center aspect-square right-5">
    <%= current_user_active_count %>
  </span>
</span>
```

As shown above, the first tag of the two nested tags is ignored and only the second tag is rendered.
I think it's a writing style problem, but how can I render the desired html?
I would appreciate it if you could advise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat` to accumulate content into the output buffer:

```rb
tag.span class: "flex w-5 h-5 ml-3" do
  concat tag.span(class: "animate-ping inline-flex h-full w-full rounded-full aspect-square bg-indigo-400 opacity-75")
  concat tag.span(current_user_active_count, class: "relative inline-flex w-5 h-5 rounded-full bg-indigo-500 text-gray-200 justify-center aspect-square right-5")
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However the way you taught me didn't give me the html I wanted because the second tag was nested inside the first tag.
The rendered html is below

Comment: <span class="flex w-5 h-5 ml-3">   
 <span class="animate-ping inline-flex h-full w-full rounded-full aspect-square bg-indigo-400 opacity-75">     
  <span class="relative inline-flex w-5 h-5 rounded-full bg-indigo-500 text-gray-200 justify-center aspect-square right-5">   
   11    
  </span>   
 </span>   
</span>.

Comment: I want the second and third tags to be nested at the same level as the first tag, but is it possible?

Comment: Ah yes sorry! Updated with the proper solution via `concat`

Comment: Greate! I did it.
There is such a way to use concat! ? I learned a lot.
Thank you very much.